# Clear Modal With External Content Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Full disclaimer - i am slightly terrible at jQuery and im just messing about with bootstrap and would love a little help.

I am creating a page that has several modal links - these links will load external content into a modal. I want to use the same modal and just reload the content. But the content is not refreshing - regardless of the second link i click to fill the modal, the content from the first click is present.

After some research on SO i have found various answers with the same (or similar) code snippets that seem very simple and are working for many other users. But i just cant get mine to work. I feel i am making a very silly error due to my lack of jQuery experience.

From what i have been able to deduce - for some reason the event is not firing at all. Even when i replace the function with a simple alert it still does not fire.

Could someone possibly take a quick look and point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
    $(document.body).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myModal').removeData('bs.modal')
    });
</script>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te"><img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" src="/img/loading.gif"></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

EDIT: Created standalone test page shown below to try and help someone spot my probably very silly error.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('triggered')
});
</script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"><div class="te"><img class="img-responsive" style="margin:0 auto;" src="/img/loading.gif"></div></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign event to #myModal

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    //do your thing here
});
```

Check the documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Special jsfiddle for you my friend:
http://jsfiddle.net/ys969vn5/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have actually read that document while trying to figure it out but presumed i was doing everything it said. I have replaced my jQuery with the following and there is still no alert showing.<script>
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    });
</script>

Comment: As you can see it works in the fiddle. May be you missed something @loveforfire33

Comment: Just created a test page that has the same result and edited my question. Could you please take a look. It's probably a very humiliating error i am causing :)

Comment: put javascript inside `$(function(){})` @loveforfire33

Answer (score 1):

This will empty the html in the modal header, body and footer.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myModal .modal-header, #myModal .modal-body, #myModal .modal-footer').html('');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have replaced my jQuery with the following and there is still no alert showing.
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myModal .modal-header, #myModal .modal-body, #myModal .modal-footer').html('');
    });
</script>

Comment: How i copied it is exactly how i used it. Thanks again